# Case when with else for every 'When' condition

Tags: sql, case, impala

I am having a table where date formats are different. I am trying to write below query which has logic as if department is A, and if date equals a 01-Oct-2010 it is null else keep the original date with format changed. I am executing it in Impala. There are various date formats which are like :

```
M/d/yyyy
MM/d/yyyy
dd-MM-yyyy
```

etc

My query goes like this.

```
 select   
 CASE WHEN y.dept='MDM'  
    CASE  WHEN 
     a.date=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date,'M/d/yyyy'),'M/d/yyyy') 
     AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 
    'M/d/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') ='10-01-2010 00:00:00' THEN null
                 ELSE from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 
'M/d/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') 
 else
     WHEN a.date=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 
    'MM/dd/yyyy'),'MM/dd/yyyy')   
    AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd 
   HH:mm:ss') ='10-01-2010 00:00:00' THEN null
   ELSE from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd 
   HH:mm:ss') 
End 

Case WHEN a.date=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 
'M/dd/yyyy'),'M/dd/yyyy') 
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 'M/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd 
HH:mm:ss') ='10-01-2010 00:00:00' THEN null
ELSE from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 'M/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd 
HH:mm:ss') End End

FROM Table INNER JOIN Table Y
ON y.id=a.id WHERE y.dept='MDM'
```

I am comparing date format of A.date -If it matches

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date,'M/d/yyyy'),'M/d/yyyy')
```

and

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 'M/d/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') matches 1-Oct-2010
```

then null , 
if not then keep original date with format changed to 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.

The trouble is my Case statement throws error. I can run all the case When's with a Final Else statement correctly, but here I need an ELSE for every WHEN as my date format is different. A single ELSE at the end would render most of my date formats to be unrecognised and give a NULL value. 
Any inputs to correct this case statement will be helpful

Comment: *"My query goes like this."* - No, it doesn't. That's full of syntax errors.

Comment: Also, it does not make any sense. How can `a.date = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date,'M/d/yyyy'),'M/d/yyyy')` ever be **not** true? I mean, you are comparing `a.date` to *itself*, what do you expect? Further, what's the point of `CASE WHEN y.dept='MDM'` when the same query contains `WHERE y.dept='MDM'`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that boolean [lazy/short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) applies here and assuming the error is thrown from the `from_unixtime()` function, you could first check that the result of `unix_timestamp()` is valid BEFORE passing that result into `from_unixtime()` which would avoid the error.

E.g. `CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(a.date,'M/d/yyyy') > 0 AND a.date=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date,'M/d/yyyy'),'M/d/yyyy') ...`